# How to check if user subscription is up to date?

Tags: braintree

1. I create new customer with credit card using `gateway.customer.create`
2. I create new subscription for a customer using `gateway.subscription.create`

Now when my application starts I have to check if customers subscriptions is still valid. Is there any api endpoint that will allow me to do this?

I am looking for example for a method like this:

```
isUserSubscribed(customerId)
```

Maybe also something to get info in which plan user is subscribed (silver,gold,etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, feel free to [reach out to our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

When you [get a customer](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/customers/search#single_customer) from Braintree, you [get all of its credit cards](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/customers/details#_3) and [subscriptions](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/credit_cards/details#_2):

```
customer = gateway.customer.find(customerId)
subscriptions = customer.credit_cards.flat_map(&:subscriptions)
```

You can then look at the customer's subscriptions to find any info you need.